# Solving linear equations with block structure and weak coupling

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, newton-raphson, hessian-matrix

I have a standard set of linear equations $Ax=b$ where the Hessian matrix $A$ has the special block structure as shown:

$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
T & U\\ 
U^T & V
\end{pmatrix}$,

$x=
\begin{pmatrix}
c\\ 
d
\end{pmatrix}$

Where $A$ is square Hessian matrix and each dimension is of size $n = c_n + d_n$. This compound dimension is quite large, typically $10^6-10^{10}$.

One can think of the matrices $T$ and $V$ as two different basis expansions of a given problem with the coupling between these two bases represented by $U$. This set of linear equations is usually solved through CG or an associated method as the matrix $A$ is too large to store.

What is interesting about this is that the "coupling" block $U$ is quite small. Also, block $T$ has a well known preconditioner that makes this block very simple to solve; however, $V$ is much more difficult to converge.

It would appear that this can be solved in a somewhat decoupled manner where were $Ax$ Hessian-vector guesses can be split as follows:

$Ax_1 = T*c + U*d$

$Ax_2 = U^T*c + V*d$

For example, $Ax_1$ could be updated on every third iteration of $Ax_2$. As the computation of $Ax_1$ is much more costly than $Ax_2$ this would be quite advantageous.

I assume that this kind of system is well described somewhere, but have been unable to google the correct combination of words. Does anyone know what this kind of system of equations is called?

Also, if anyone has a good recommendation for material on approximate Newton methods for ill-conditioned systems that would be quite helpful as well.

---

Whats going on here? I would have expected at least some response by now. Is there any particular issue with the question?

Comment: (1) Conventionally, block representations of matrices have capital letters for matrices and lowercase letters for column/row vectors. Can you reformat your problem to clarify what are blocks and what are vectors? It also greatly helps to identify the size of each component (e.g., if $A$ is $(n \times n)$, then maybe $t$ is $(r\times s)$ and $u$ is $(r \times (n-s))$, etc.)    (2) Your presence of zeros underneath $c$ reminds me of a QR decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix

Comment: @Xoque55 Sorry no 0's, just $o$'s. I have updated the problem to reflect blocks and vectors a bit better.